# Varnish with urlEncoded parameters

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm new to Varnish but I'm trying to use it as a reverse proxy. Everyting is fine except that when the application append url encoded parameters to the request it never goes to a server.

We try to remove parameters from the hash, but it doesn't seems to be the source of our troubles

```
sub vcl_hash {
     hash_data(regsub(req.url, "\?.*", ""));
     return (hash);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure out what is happening behind the scenes with any given request is by running the `varnishlog` command an examining its output.

As for the VCL code you pasted, this tells Varnish to ignore query parameters (`?a=b&c=d&e=f`) for caching purposes.  The following URLs will therefore all refer to the same object in cache:

```
http://your.site/some_page.html
http://your.site/some_page.html?a=b&c=d&e=f
http://your.site/some_page.html?abc=xyz
```

Assuming the response is cacheable, your backend will only see the request for the first such URL it sees.  All subsequent requests (regardless of query parameters) will be served directly from cache, until the cache object expires.

You mentioned "url encoded" parameters, but unless you have VCL code that specifically deals with %XX encoded octets, they should have no effect on how Varnish handles the request.